# How to set the delta to number when buttons are clicked given step='any' on a number input?

Tags: html, input

I have an HTML form input, using X-Editable for AngularJS (https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form)

```
<span editable-number="qaRow.threshold1" e-required e-name="threshold1" e-step="0.1" e-form="tableform">
```

This is an `input box` that accepts numbers. 
I would like to **add/subtract 0.1** when the **'up' / 'down' buttons are clicked** (or those inside the input box).

**This is actually implemented above.**

The thing is that I want this input to accept **any** number (not just x.y, but also x.yz). Is there any efficient way to implement this?

Something like `step="any" step-size="0.1"`?
Thanks!

Comment: _“This is an input box that accepts numbers”_ - not, it is not - it’s a simple span element. So if this has any kind of input functionality, some JavaScript must probably have added it. But since you neglected to tell us which one that is/what it does, we can’t tell you anything more right now.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for the comment. I've updated the question. Please take a look at https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form